# ARMA model for monthly price returns based on daily data. is rolling window claibration ok?

Tags: arima, prediction-interval

If i have daily prices for 5 years, and want to predict monthly relative returns , is rolling window calibration is used for ARMA(and thus use all available data) ? or it's better to use just one window for monthly returns(but have fewer points)?

What is the best practice? (given that ARMA has lag terms)

Answer (score 0):

The industry practice is to use a rolling window of a fixed or varying size. Using one big estimation window to make predictions at different moments of time is dangerous. The window is sure to contain a moment of structural change. So different window segments will describe different dynamics.

Comment: how to decide varying window size? there's no problem that ARMA contains   lag terms, so there's high artificial correlation between lag terms?